# Whats the deal with these Wifi Connections

Tags: wireless-networking

Alright, you guys may or may not be able to help me with this issue.  I'm recovering a password from a laptop of mine using WirelessKeyView.

Here are my results thus far:

[image]

I know for a fact that that `Lunenburg` has a password, however, it doesn't display a result for a password.  `Educate4Wake` has a password but the laptop isn't actually connected to it but they do have the password stored as you can see.

The other thing about this is that `Educate4Wake` is has its SSID hidden.

Anyways, with that in mind, does this set up match anything you guys have ever seen?  We were able to get a mobile device to connect to `Educate4Wake` but with no actual internet access.

I'm not exactly the most knowledgeable about networking (esp. wireless) so I appreciate your help!

Comment: What exactly is your question? It makes no sense in its current form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [WirelessKeyView FAQ](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_wep_key_faq.html):

> **Q: I run WirelessKeyView, and it gives me a very long WPA-PSK key under the 'Key (Hex)' column, which is not the original key that I used. Can I retrieve the original Ascii key?**
>
> A: In Windows XP, after you type a WPA-PSK key, it automatically converted into a 256-bit key that is displayed by WirelessKeyView in 'Key (Hex)' column. This new key cannot be converted back to the original key that you typed, but you can use this key to connect to the wireless network exactly like the original key.  In Windows Vista, the WPA-PSK key is not converted into another key, so you can retrieve the original key that you typed.